# Finding out location of view code from Xcode view debugging

Tags: xcode, xcode7, view-debugging

Xcode's view debugging provides the memory address, color, etc. of a subview, but it does not contain any info on where the view code reside (or the name of image contained in an image view) or which view controller contains the current view being examined.  Basically, it's very hard to trace back from the debugged view to where the code reside, unlike a callstack that shows you exactly where things are.

How can I navigate from view debugging to the right view controller class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a APP which named "Reveal", this can provide the view layout when debugging.